# Настройка разрешения установки приложений не из Маркета

Tags: java, android

Необходимо узнать следующее:

Распространяю приложение в обход Маркета. Каждый раз пользователю нужно заходить в "Настройки" -> "Установка из неизвестных источников", чтобы установить. В общем, трудно для пользователя.

Есть ли какие-то способы подписать приложение, добавить какие-то сертификаты или что-то еще, что позволит прямо по ссылке (возможно просто с нажатием какой-нибудь кнопки "Доверять") установить приложение без умственного напряга пользователя заходить в Настройки?

В общем, цель: максимально не напрягать пользователя в вопросе настроек. Как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: К сожалению никак

Comment: К счастью никак.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы приложения умели обходить установку только из доверенных источников, то такая настройка потеряла бы смысл.
Поэтому никак, кроме как вручную в настройках разрешить установку из недоверенных источников, нельзя.